# Java Iterate Over Collection ,not working as expected

Tags: java

I am currently working on a Java project, below are my attempts at coding so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 *
 * This class models a zoo. It allows a single animal to be added to the zoo, a
 * batch of animals to be "imported" by reading data from a text file and for all
 * the animals to be listed in a terminal window.  It also ensures that all animals
 * in the zoo have a unique identifier.
 *


public class MyZoo
{
   // zoo identifier
   private String zooId;
   // a number used in generating a unique identifier for the next animal to be added to the zoo
   private int nextAnimalIdNumber;
   // zstorage for the Animal objects
   private TreeMap<String, Animal> animals;

   /**
    * Create an "empty" zoo.
    *
    * @param zooId an identifier for the zoo, at least three characters long.
    */
   public MyZoo(String zooId)
   {
      this.zooId = zooId.trim().substring(0,3).toUpperCase();
      nextAnimalIdNumber = 0;
      animals = new TreeMap<String, Animal>();
   }

   /**
    * Returns a unique identifier, for an <tt>Animal</tt> object, based on the
    * zoo identifier and the field <tt>nextAnimalIdNumber</tt> which is incremented
    * ready for next time the method is called.
    *
    * @return a unique identifier.
    */
   public String allocateId()
   {
      // increment nextAnimalIdNumber and then construct a six digit string from it
      nextAnimalIdNumber++;
      String s = Integer.toString(nextAnimalIdNumber);
      while ( s.length()<6 )
        s = "0" + s;
      return zooId + "_" +  s;
   }

   /**
    * Adds an animal to the zoo.
    *
    * @param animal the Animal object to be added.
    */
   public void addAnimal(Animal animal)
   {
      animals.put(animal.getName(), animal);
   }

   /**
    * Reads <tt>Animal</tt> data from a text file and adds them to the zoo.  The
    * format of the data is specified in the MyZoo coursework assignment.
    *
    * @param animal the Animal object to be added.
    */
   public void readDataFromFile()
   {
      int noOfAnimalsRead = 0;

      // set up an owner for the FileDialog
      JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
      jframe.setVisible(true);
      // use a Filedialog to select a file to read from
      FileDialog fDialog = new FileDialog(jframe, "Read from", FileDialog.LOAD);
      fDialog.setFile("import001.txt");
      fDialog.setDirectory(".");
      fDialog.setVisible(true);
      String fname = fDialog.getFile();
      jframe.dispose();

       File inFile = new File(fname);

    String fileName = "import002.txt";

        // This will reference one line at a time
        String line = null;


        try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader = 
                new FileReader(fileName);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }   

            // Always close files.
            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                fileName + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                + fileName + "'");                  

        }

      addAnimal( new Animal("golden eagle", "Eddie", this) );               //
      addAnimal( new Animal("tiger", "Tommy", this) );            
      addAnimal( new Animal("lion", "Leo", this) );         
      addAnimal( new Animal("parrot", "Polly", this) );             
      addAnimal( new Animal("cobra", "Collin", this) );       

      noOfAnimalsRead = 5;                                       

      // this next line should be retained
      System.out.println("no of animals read from file was " + noOfAnimalsRead + "\n");
   }

   /**
    * Prints out details of all animal in the zoo.
    *
    */
   public void printAllAnimals()
   {

      System.out.println("\nDetails for all animals in Zoo " + zooId);
      System.out.println(  "==================================");

      Collection<Animal> c = animals.values();
    // The name of the file to open.
        String fileName = "import001.txt";

        // This will reference one line at a time
        String line = null;

        TreeMap sortedItems = new TreeMap(animals);

   // keySet returns the Map's keys, which will be sorted because it's a treemap.
   for(Object s: animals.keySet()) {

       // Yeah, I hate this too.
       String k = (String) s;

       // but now we have the key to the map.

       // Now you can get the AnimalItems.  
       List<Animal> listOfanimals = animals.get(s);

       // Iterate over this list for the associated animals
       for(AnimalItem animalItem: listOfAnimalanimals) {
          System.out.println(animalItem.getSomething());
          }
       }                                         
   }
}
```

I currently cannot get the printAllAnimals() method to work as it should.

When executing the method printAllAnimals(), it does not do anything, when it is supposed to use the Collection object c, so that animals stored in the zoo can easily be checked

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am confused.

Comment: Put types on your `TreeMap sortedItems` (i.e. `Map<String, Animal>`) and you don't need the cast.

Comment: Also you could just loop over the `values()` or `entrySet()` rather than looping over the keys and then fetching the value for each key.

Comment: if you want to store key as string and value as list of animals why didn't you use guava Multimap http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Answer (score 2):

What is this?

```
List<Animal> listOfanimals = animals.get(s); // list is listOfanimals

// Iterate over this list for the associated animals
for(AnimalItem animalItem: listOfAnimalanimals) { // what is listOfAnimalanimals?
      System.out.println(animalItem.getSomething());
   }
}
```

Change to

```
for(AnimalItem animalItem: listOfanimals) { 
      System.out.println(animalItem.getSomething());
   }
}
```

Please use debugger, This kind of issue you can figure out by your own.